# PKCS8EncodedKeySpec able to decode RSA PrivateKey in PKCS#1 and PKCS#8 format. But, not for Ec algorithm

Tags: java, rsa, pem, pkcs#8, pkcs#1

I have a scenario where I put RSA/EC private key (created by `openssl`) in JSON payload. I have my customized parser where I look for banners and fetch the information between them.

Now for RSA key irrespective whether it is PKCS#1 (default openssl) or PKCS#8 following code is working:

```
KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
PrivateKey privateKey  = factory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes));
```

where `privateKeyBytes` is decoded base64 byte of private key. Private key is in the PEM format I put in JSON payload.

However when I create private key for EC algorithm via openssl, same piece of code is giving following error:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
    java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : version mismatch:
    (supported: 00, parsed: 01)
```

When I convert created pem to PKCS#8 format via (`openssl pkcs8` command) then it works.

Note: My code uses `"SUNRSA"` provider for RSA algorithm and `"SUNEC"` provider for EC algorithm.

The RSA KEYS for example are generated in following manner:
Note: KeySize is the size of key you want to generate i.e 1024/2048 etc.

```
public static KeyPair generateRsaKeyPair(int keySizeInBits) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    KeyPairGenerator r = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    r.initialize(keySizeInBits, RandomUtil.getSecureRandom());
    KeyPair keypair = r.generateKeyPair();
    return keypair;
}
```

And EC key pair is generated as follows:
Note: CurveType is the type of curve used for EC algorithm key pair generation eg: prime256v1

```
public static KeyPair generateEcKeyPair(String curveType) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC","BC");

    ECGenParameterSpec ecsp = new ECGenParameterSpec(curveType);
    kpg.initialize(ecsp, new SecureRandom());

    KeyPair kpU = kpg.generateKeyPair();
    return kpU;
}
```

Comment: Which Java runtime (OS, Java version, Java runtime vendor)? Some OpenJDK8 packages are known to have problems with it's EC implementation.

Comment: @Robert: openjdk version "1.8.0_191"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
JAVA 8 I am currently using.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm skeptical. Factory with `PKCS8` spec should NOT accept PKCS1 format, or anything other than PKCS8 format (_containing_ the algorithm format here PKCS1). Can you post an example 'PKCS1' privatekey that works for you? (Obviously only a key you _don't_ use for any real data.)

Comment: Please at least show how the keys are generated / encoded. As it currently stands we don't know the input, so we cannot really answer the question.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I have added APIs for both RSA and EC keys generation. Please have a look.

Comment: Maybe pass in the algorithm name to the `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec()` constructor?